# jquery mouseover() isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this bit of jquery which is meant to add class called "wow rubberBand" which is a special class that gives an animation to the element.

However for some reason the animation isn't kicking in.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="wow.min.js"></script>
<script>new WOW().init();</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("header").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").addClass("wow rubberBand");

    })
    $("header").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find("span").removeClass("wow rubberBand");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: Edited my code but still isn't doing what it supposed to do ...

Comment: with `$(this).find("span")` this action will run for every `span` inside `header` .. What are you trying to do??  and what is `new WOW().init();` for??

Comment: If you keep editing your initial code - no one will be able to tell what all these comments mean - and the thread becomes meaningless. It's best to leave things are you initially put them up / with exceptions for major errors or grammar and spelling or formatting.

Comment: @sherrifderek  Well .... but if I don't edit my code others can't tell how far I've come to resolve this ???

Comment: No one cares about how far you've come - but if they are looking up an issue they are having, they want to see what other people came up with - and then the solutions and discussions that it's spawned. If you correct all your code... then it will just show correct code... that's not what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`  on the top of the page

Comment: Actually I've got it placed above the code I posted here. At the end of the html page. It's just different version but it shouldn't matter much. But will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic syntax errors in your code, as @Andreas commented, instead of `$(this).attr("class","wow rubberBand");` and `$(this).attr("class","");`

use

`$(this).addClass("wow rubberBand");` and `$(this).removeClass("wow rubberBand")`;

Comment: Edited. Working on going down to resolve this bit step by step. This can work.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain your mouse events like this:

```
$thing = $('.thing'); // 'query' for this dom element and cache it - you can do this with your span things for example... 

$thing
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  })
;

// this is the same...
$('.hover-thing').hover( function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("blue");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/b5y6mrb0/

You could also use `.hover()` or CSS `:hover` - depending on what you are doing. I very rarely find myself reaching for mouseenter

Despite the comments: `$(this).attr('class', '');` and `$(this).attr('class', 'className');` - are totally valid ways of changing a class attr. The negative part is that you'll clobber any existing classes if you remove al of them - so `removeClass()` is a helper that checks for that particular class in the array of classes and removes just that one.

Comment: Well ... this is first time I'm using mouse events too. But only because I'm adding animation to a paragraph which is already working on my other website. It's an effect that can't be achieved with CSS.

Comment: The difference is on my other website that animation kicks in everytime the page is loaded but here I'm trying to animate the paragraph every time the mouse hovers over it.

Comment: Yeah ... I just tried to apply the animation in the same way like I did with the other animation and it works. It just doesn't seem to work with mouse events ...

Comment: Well, whatever is happening or not happening - it's not programmed properly. All this stuff - works in the language and in the way the browser implements that language. That's why it's best to keep the example really simple. Hundreds of things could be effecting the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because you have to attach the eventhandler on the document, or maybe its just an syntax error ("header" should be ".header")

```
(function ($) {
    $( document ).on( 'mouseenter', '.header', {}, function( e ) {
        console.log( "hover" );
    });
})(jQuery);
```